# Performance of IDE HDDs on the same cable

Tags: hard-drive, performance, pata

What are the performance implications (if any) of two IDE HDDs:

- being on the same cable (=IDE channel) vs on different cables (channels) of the same IDE controller?
- using different Ultra-ATA modes while on the same cable?